# Showing a set is open/closed/both/neither

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the set $U=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,\colon |z|>1, \Im{(z)}\ge0\}$. Is this set open, closed, both or neither.

---

I stated it was neither since if we take a point $z\in U$ with $\Im{(z)}=0$, we cannot find an $\varepsilon>0$ positive such that $D(z,\varepsilon)\subset U$.

Furthermore, it is not closed since its complement is not open, following a similar argument however now we take a point on the curve $|z|=1$ satisfying $\Im{(z)}<0$.

---

Is this correct or am I missing something (apart from the obvious detail and providing particular counterexamples)?

Comment: You write "if we take a point $z\in U$ with $\Im(z) \ge 0$, we cannot find an $\varepsilon>0$ ... such that $D(z,\varepsilon)\subset U$." As written this is not true. Take the point $z=2i \in U$, and you'll find that $\varepsilon =1$ satisfies $D(z,\varepsilon) \subset U$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Woops I mean if we take a point $\Im{(z)}=0$. Typo!

Comment: Looks like there's another typo, i.e. in the second case take a point on $|z|=1$ satisfying $\Im(z)>0$. Otherwise, it looks fine to me.